# Changing column name pandas with utf-16 encoding

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, unicode

I am reading a utf-16 csv file to a pandas dataframe, this works fine but I want to change some column names that have some strange encoding. To check column names I use

```
a =list(df.columns.values)
```

and get

```
a = [u'ID',
u'Injection Name',
u'Solvent',
u'Injection Time [ms]',
u'Duration [min]',
u'Target Fractional Surface Coverage',
u'Actual Fractional Surface Coverage',
u'Column Temperature [Kelvin]',
u'Column Pressure Drop [Torr]',
u'Exit Flow Rate [sccm]',
u'Peak Area [\xb5V\u2022min]',
u'Peak Max (Signal) [\xb5V]']
```

I want to change the name of  'Peak Area [\xb5V\u2022min]' and 
 'Peak Max (Signal) [\xb5V].

Usually I would do

```
df.rename(columns={'Peak Area [\xb5V\u2022min]':'peak_area','Peak Max (Signal) [\xb5V]' : 'peak_max_signal'},inplace=True)
```

For some reason this doesn't work. I get error saying

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'peak_area'
```

I have no idea how to fix this

Comment: What does `df.columns[-2]` show and would that work? `df.rename(columns={df.columns[-2]:'peak_area',df.columns[-1] : 'peak_max_signal'},inplace=True)`

Comment: Yeah that worked, thanks.  Still interesting why my way didn't work.

Comment: you probably just have to keep the `u` : `df.rename(columns={u'Peak Area [\xb5V\u2022min]':'peak_area',...` . In python 3 this doesn't matter.